# NameError: name 'compile_and_fit' is not defined

Tags: python, time-series, lstm, forecasting

```
history = compile_and_fit(lstm_model, wide_window)

IPython.display.clear_output()
val_performance['LSTM'] = lstm_model.evaluate(wide_window.val)
performance['LSTM'] = lstm_model.evaluate(wide_window.test, verbose=0)
```

when I run this code it gives me an error that "compile_and_fit is not defined" whereas the same code is executable in tensorflow's colab documentation.

Comment: I think you have not defined 'compile_and_fit' function before calling the function. Check out the tensorflow documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/overfit_and_underfit. you can search the function here and implement it similarly.

Answer (score 1):

```
MAX_EPOCHS = 20

def compile_and_fit(model, window, patience=2):
  early_stopping = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                                    patience=patience,
                                                    mode='min')

  model.compile(loss=tf.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
                optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
                metrics=[tf.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()])

  history = model.fit(window.train, epochs=MAX_EPOCHS,
                      validation_data=window.val,
                      callbacks=[early_stopping])
  return history
```

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#linear_model